# User Defined Function with multiple parameters is returning NULL value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to convert a python function to PySpark user defined function as below:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,col,array
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType,IntegerType,DecimalType
from datetime import date

def calculateAmount(loandate,loanamount):
    y,m,d = loandate.split('-')[0],loandate.split('-')[1],loandate.split('-')[2]
    ld = date(int(y),int(m),int(d))
    if (date(2010,1,1) <= ld <= date(2015,12,31)):
        fine = 10
    elif (date(2016,1,1) <=ld <= date.today()):
        fine = 5
    return ((100+fine)*int(loanamount))/100

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("User Defined Functions").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.options(delimiter = "\t",header = True).csv("../input/applicationloan/loan.txt")

calAmount = udf(lambda interest,amount : calculateAmount(interest,amount),DecimalType())

df = df.withColumn("NewLoanAmount",calAmount(col("loandate"),col("loanamount")))
df.show()
```

Output of above code is below:

[image: Output]

Screenshot of source file "loan.txt":

[image: loan.txt]

The above source file is tab delimited.

I am creating a new column "NewLoanAmount" using PySpark `udf`. But PySpark `udf` is returning me "NULL" values. It seems to be an issue with calling of lambda function in the PySpark `udf`.

How to write PySpark UDF with multiple parameters? I understand writing PySpark UDF with single parameter. But working with multiple parameters seems to be confusing.

Comment: I don't want to use decorator. I want to understand the implementation of udf with multiple parameters using lambda function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your data, you should not create UDF. It's easily done using native Spark functions:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('John', '01', '89', 20000, '2020-10-01'),
     ('Monty', '02', '45', 10000, '2015-05-05'),
     ('Roxy', '03', '76', 30000, '2010-10-10')],
    ['name', 'id', 'loannum', 'loanamount', 'loandate'])

def calculateAmount(loandate, loanamount):
    fine = F.when(F.col('loandate').between('2010-01-01', '2015-12-31'), 10) \
            .when(F.col('loandate').between('2016-01-01', F.current_date()), 5)
    return ((100 + fine) * F.col('loanamount').cast('long')) / 100

df = df.withColumn("NewLoanAmount", calculateAmount("loandate", "loanamount"))

df.show()
# +-----+---+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
# |name |id |loannum|loanamount|loandate  |NewLoanAmount|
# +-----+---+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
# |John |01 |89     |20000     |2020-10-01|21000.0      |
# |Monty|02 |45     |10000     |2015-05-05|11000.0      |
# |Roxy |03 |76     |30000     |2010-10-10|33000.0      |
# +-----+---+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

---

To answer the original question...

You already have the function definition, so `lambda` is not needed. And overall, it's simpler to use the decorator `@udf` instead of the line
`calAmount = udf(lambda interest,amount : calculateAmount(interest,amount),DecimalType())`

The following works:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col, array
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType, DecimalType
from datetime import date

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('John', '01', '89', 20000, '2020-10-01'),
     ('Monty', '02', '45', 10000, '2015-05-05'),
     ('Roxy', '03', '76', 30000, '2010-10-10')],
    ['name', 'id', 'loannum', 'loanamount', 'loandate'])

@udf
def calculateAmount(loandate, loanamount):
    y, m, d = loandate.split('-')[0], loandate.split('-')[1], loandate.split('-')[2]
    ld = date(int(y), int(m), int(d))
    if (date(2010, 1, 1) <= ld <= date(2015, 12, 31)):
        fine = 10
    elif (date(2016, 1, 1) <= ld <= date.today()):
        fine = 5
    return ((100 + fine) * int(loanamount)) / 100

df = df.withColumn("NewLoanAmount", calculateAmount(col("loandate"), col("loanamount")))

df.show()
# +-----+---+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
# |name |id |loannum|loanamount|loandate  |NewLoanAmount|
# +-----+---+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
# |John |01 |89     |20000     |2020-10-01|21000.0      |
# |Monty|02 |45     |10000     |2015-05-05|11000.0      |
# |Roxy |03 |76     |30000     |2010-10-10|33000.0      |
# +-----+---+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

---

A way without the `@udf` decorator:

```
calAmount = udf(calculateAmount)
```

or

```
calAmount = udf(calculateAmount, DoubleType())
```

In your original code, you provide `DecimalType()`, but Python does not do calculations in decimal numbers. Your calculations are done on double precision numbers, not decimals. So, your result is a double precision number, while Spark expects to get a decimal number... This is why you get nulls. To make the python function to return a decimal, you would need to use [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) library. Without it, it's just double precision numbers.

Comment: @aws_sangram - and `lambda` is not needed, as you already have a `def` function. You can use one or the other, as both define a function.

Comment: DoubleType() works instead of DecimalType(). Thanks a lot.